# Store data in LINQ to two tables; Join LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, simplemembership

I am using simplemembership with MVC4 which is work great, however i am required to add addition user details like first and last name, email, country with constraints each user can have multiple profiles so i add ID {FK} from Users table in UserProfile table. 
I have seprate form when user register, system call to another form asking addition details. I am using code first existing database approach

I missing puzzle of how to store additional information along saying hock its user profile using LINQ.

many thanks in advance ..

### Database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserProfile] (
[UserId]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[UserName] NVARCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
[ID]       INT            NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC),
FOREIGN KEY ([ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([ID])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
[ID]         INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Email]      NVARCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
[First_Name] NVARCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
[Last_Name]  NVARCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
[Country]    NVARCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);
```

### Controller class

```
  [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult UserDetail()
    {

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult UserDetail(User model)
    {

        using (var db = new DB5Context_01())
        {
            var user_info = new User
            {
                First_Name = model.First_Name,
                Last_Name = model.Last_Name,
                Country = model.Country,
                Email = model.Email
            };

           //// need help here ??? hock Userprofile with User

        }
```

### SimpleMemberShip Initializing

```
namespace Simple_LoginSystem_05.Filters
{
public class InitializeSimpleMembership : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public InitializeSimpleMembership()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
            {
                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
        }
    }
}
}
```

### Model

```
  public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.UserProfiles = new HashSet<UserProfile>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
```

Comment: Are your table names mixed up?  There's no way that's right

Comment: i guess not ... what i am saying each user can have many UserProfiles, but each UserProfile belongs to one user

Comment: just create a List<UserProfile> and fill it in for each UserProfile belonging to the User

Comment: how i do the LINQ part if i m asking right question

Comment: @toxic, its hard to understand the part of your question reading "_along saying hock its user profile_", can you edit that please?

Answer (score 0):

SimpleMembership expects a single "UserProfile" per user, which it stores in the table you specify in your call to:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

In the default code that table is called "UserProfile", which matches up with `UserProfile` in `AccountModels.cs`. See the detail section 4 of [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16734651/1945631) for more information about `UserProfile`.

I should also note that if it wasn't for your requirement "*each user can have multiple profiles*" then you normally just add the properties such as Email, FirstName, LastName, Country to the `UserProfile` class. I also move that class out of `UsersContext` into my own context, delete `UsersContext` and update the references from `UsersContext` to my own context in `AccountController` and `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute` (you could even [set the Email as the login token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529469/simplemembership-adding-email-field-and-use-as-login-name/16531180#16531180) instead of the `UserName` using this approach).

So, while I don't understand how a single user needs more than one FirstName etc., assuming you have a good reason for this then for your instance you are going to have to introduce new terms, something like:

- `UserProfile` - keep this meaning the SimpleMembership `UserProfile` as it will make it easier to read the documentation. There will be one record per login in this table.
- `AttributesForUser` - I will use this to describe your requirement "*additional user details like first and last name, email, country with constraints each user can have multiple profiles*". It seems like this corresponds to your `User` table above. Using the name `User` for this table will cause clashes with `User` from the membership and `WebSecurity` framework methods and properties so is maybe not the best idea. Each entry in the table `UserProfiles` can have one or more entries in the table `AttributesForUsers`.

It looks like you already have the code-first details sorted. Your example of `public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }` is correct, but you would change this to:

```
public virtual ICollection<AttributesForUser> AttributesForUser { get; set; }
```

And then your `AttributesForUser` (which you also add as a DbSet to your data context) would look like:

```
public class AttributesForUser
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

When you create a user, you can then do:

```
using (MyContextdb = new MyContext())
{
  WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
  // assumes you have moved UserProfile to MyContext, alter code accordingly if not
  UserProfile userProfile = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.ToLower() == model.UserName.ToLower());
  AttributesForUser newAttribs = new AttributesForUser { 
    UserId = userProfile.UserId,
    ... fill in other properties here ... 
  };
  db.AttributesForUsers.Add(newAttribs);
  // do as many more newAttribs as you need for this userId
  ...
  // and now save
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```