# How to make email as User Name in mvc-4 simplemembership?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using simple membership in asp.net MVC 4, i changed user name as a email, id and i successfully able to create the USER. But when i login with the credentials it says either user name or password is incorrect.
How can i fix it?

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.Email, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
            {
                //eturn RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                return Content("Logged In");
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return PartialView("_UserLoginPartial",model);
        }
```

Comment: There's a good answer about this here which may help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529469/simplemembership-adding-email-field-and-use-as-login-name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529469/simplemembership-adding-email-field-and-use-as-login-name)

Comment: i can register but i can't login...

Comment: Have you looked at the checklist in that link and made sure you've made all the changes necessary? e.g. changing your login model

Comment: yes i changed every thing..

Comment: i dont want an email field in the database, i need to insert email type in the UserName. And for the login i want to check this mail id as a suername in the userProfile table.

Comment: i was require to make false, last parameter int the websecutiy.register method for admin authentication.